# How to string two variables together in php

Tags: php

I am new to php. And string concatenation is difficult for me. I want to concatenate the following string:

```
$branch = 'apple';
$rules = "(product=='iphone')andManufacturer==".$branch;
// result "(product == 'iphone')andManufacturer ==apple"
```

But the string I want:

```
"(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='apple'"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(Added single quote to the string):

```
$branch = 'apple';
$rules = "(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='".$branch."'";
echo $rules;
```

Another solution(Wrap the single quotes in double quotes to branch variable):

```
$branch = "'apple'";
$rules = "(product=='iphone')andManufacturer==".$branch;
echo $rules;
```

OUTPUT:

```
(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly put your $branch variable in "" quotes, no need for concatenation.

```
$branch = 'apple';
$rules = "(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='$branch'";
echo $rules;
```

OR

```
$branch = "'apple'";
$rules = "(product=='iphone')andManufacturer==" . $branch;
echo $rules;
```

OUTPUT:

```
(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check functions like [sprintf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) and [printf()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php)

```
$rules = sprintf("(product=='iphone')andManufacturer=='%s'", $branch);
```